# Convert postgres to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have an SQL file generated from a Postgres database that I want to run on SQL Server 2008. The SQL file creates, drops and inserts data into tables. SQL Server returns a number of errors in the syntax.

Is there a way to make the file compatible?

If not, what is the best way to export data from Postgres to SQL Server?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/65407/best-tool-to-migrate-a-postgresql-database-to-ms-sql-2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is usually to restore the dump to a PostgreSQL server, then copy the data out of the live server using:

- A schema-only dump you hand-convert, followed by a `pg_dump --data-only --inserts` dump that might load as-is if you're lucky, and otherwise can be machine converted with text processing tools; or
- A dedicated conversion tool if you can find one for Pg -> MS SQL. Maybe the [MS SQL ODBC dump/export tool](https://serverfault.com/questions/65407/best-tool-to-migrate-a-postgresql-database-to-ms-sql-2005) referred to in the linked post is a special case of an ETL tool.
- Usually better, use ETL tools like Talend or Pentaho to aid in the conversion.